# Monitor Raspberry pi undervoltage warning over time

Tags: pi-3, power, software-recommendation

I am looking to find a way to monitor the under-voltage warning over a longer period of time, preferably also what it currently reads as the voltage. The reason being I would like to fuse the data from it and a couple of other sensors so that I can work a little bit harder to determine exactly what is causing the voltage to drop.

Is there a way I can do any of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not monitor voltage, because the Pi has no analog capability. (You could, of course, add an ADC to monitor the voltage.)

The under-voltage warning is produced by a chip, and is ON or OFF. See[Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations) for details.

`vcgencmd get_throttled` will show the current state. You may be able to write something to monitor this, but AFAIK there is nothing currently available. See the following for detail https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=147781&start=50#p972790

Comment: I feel like the parenthetical in your first paragraph was actually the answer to the question, not a footnote. "Is there any way I can do this?"  Yes!  Add an ADC chip and use that.

Comment: `vcgencmd get_throttled` sounds pretty good to me. Knowing when it is throttled should be enough. A simple python script that polls this command's results will be very helpful. Thanks